# Implementing Binary Arithmetic

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, binary

Given two binary numbers (strings containing 0s and 1s), perform operations on them, with one problem: **You must keep them in binary.** That means no going `binary(integer(n1)+integer(n2))` or anything like that.

**Input:** Two binary numbers, `n1` and `n2`, and a number between 0 and 3, `o`, defining the operator. The two binary numbers will be the same length.

**Output:** 
If `o` is 0, return `n1+n2` as a binary number.
If `o` is 1, return `n1-n2` as a binary number.
If `o` is 2, return `n1*n2` as a binary number.
If `o` is 3, return `n1/n2` as a binary number, using floor division.
**The output will not be the same length as the input. Please truncate all leading zeros.**

If you implement Two's Complement, subtract 10% off your character count, up to a limit of 50. Truncate to `length(n1)+length(n2)` digits.

**Test Cases:**
`n1=01010, n2=10101, o=0: 11111`
`n1=11110, n2=01010, o=1: 10100`
`n1=0010, n2=1000, o=2: 10000`
`n1=1011010, n2=0010001, o=3: 101`

Shortest code wins. Good luck!

Comment: I think you should rethink the "subtract 50" thing. I can see it being implemented in much less characters than that. Perhaps "10% up to 50" would be a better choice.

Comment: When you say "binary numbers" you don't actually mean "binary numbers", do you? If you mean "strings containing only characters '0' and '1'" then *say that*.

Comment: The binary numbers will be the same length, but can we assume that there will be no overflow, so the result is the same length? (Is "n1=11111, n2=11111, o=0" possible?)

Comment: How do we represent negative numbers (i.e. what is the basis 2^n/how do we write -1)?

Comment: @schnaader The third example (multiply) shows otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. I have fixed the question, or at least I think I did. Keep it coming!

Comment: @Howard: Two's Complement

Comment: @beary605 In two's complement the most significant bit being set indicates a negative number - what is the word size we're working with here?

Comment: Do we need to truncate leading zeros?

Comment: @Gareth: Let's say a reasonable amount. Kieth Randall: Yes.

Comment: @beary605 That's not very helpful, unfortunately. Let me ask it another way: if the input is `n1=0000, n2=0001, o=1` should the output be `11111111`, `1111111111111111`, or something else?

Comment: I see what you mean now. In that case, truncate the 1s to the length(n1)+length(n2).

Comment: @beary605 Do we use this word size also for the input? That would mean that input numbers are always non-negative?

Comment: No, the input will be a random number of digits.

Comment: Truncating doesn't help in identifying negative numbers. I still think we need to know whether they're 8 digits long, 16, 32, 64 or something else. And btw.: My computer always calculates in binary. P.S.: The operator should be given as 0, 01, 10 or 11 respectively, just for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: A negative number has a turned-on bit in the front; both inputs are the same length. To me, that should be sufficient enough information.

Comment: I've never seen a datatype with 5 bits like in the examples 1 and 2. In example 3 you multiply 2 * -8, according to your last explanation. -16 is the decimal result, but it doesn't fit a 4 bit Int. Now you show a 5-bit Int as result, but in a 5 bit data type 1000 wouldn't be -8, but 8. So we have to assume an autowidening datatype? I'm fine with that, but it isn't evident from the examples alone. And, something else: You have to annotate an answer with @Name to make the system inform somebody, that you answered his comment. Tab completion works thereby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python, 429 chars - 10% bonus = 386.1

Numbers are kept in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order, which is stretching the rules a bit but makes for easier processing.  Maximum number size is 32 bits.  Addition is standard, subtraction is implemented by x-y = x+~y+1 (throwing away the carry out of the 32 bits), multiplication is done using the [Russian Peasant algorithm](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html), and division is done with repeated subtraction.

```
z,i='01'
P=z*32
def A(x,y):
 r='';c=z
 for a,b in zip(x+P,y+P):k=(a+b+c).count(i);r+='0101'[k];c='0011'[k]
 return r[:32]
S=lambda x,y:A(A(x,''.join(chr(ord(c)^1)for c in y+P)),i)
def M(x,y):
 r=''
 while y:
  if y[0]==i:r=A(r,x)
  x=z+x;y=y[1:]
 return r
def D(x,y):
 x=(x+P)[:32];y=(y+P)[:32];r=''
 while x[::-1]>=y[::-1]:r=A(r,i);x=S(x,y)
 return r
def B(x,y,o):r=[A,S,M,D][o](x,y).rstrip(z)[:len(x)+len(y)];return[r,z][r=='']
```

`B` is the function of interest, here is its result on the test cases:

```
print B('01010','10101',0)
11111
print B('01111','01010',1)
00101
print B('0100','0001',2)
00001
print B('0101101','1000100',3)
101
```

Comment: lol, only answer, so answer to you! You can replace `[A,S,M,D][o]` with `chr(65+o)` in function B if you rename your operator functions A, B, C,and D, respectively.

Comment: @beary605: I think you'd have to use `eval(chr(65+o))`, which doesn't help.

Comment: Ah yeah. :X lol

Answer (score 3):

#### Scala 785:

Let's start with a famous quote of Bjarne Stroustrup, the inventor of C++, which in his great wisdom told us:

> Don't divide without necessity!

To make a submission to this fine question, we not only have to perform division - we have to implement it! Well - let's not talk about that.

```
object B{
val(l,o)=('1',"0")
type S=String
def n(v:S,c:S)=o*(c.size-v.size)+v
def g(n:S,m:S)=((n zip m)find(a=>a._1!=a._2)).getOrElse((l,'0'))._1==l
def a(x:S,y:S)=(((x zip y):\o)((n,m)=>{val s=Seq(m(0),n._1,n._2).filter(_==l).size
Seq("00","01","10","11")(s)}+m.tail))
def P(x:S,y:S)=t(a(n(x,y),n(y,x)))
def m(a:S,b:S)=(o/:a.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1==l).map(x=>b+o*(a.size-x._2-1)))(P)
def x(x:S,y:S)=t(s(x,y))
def s(x:S,y:S)=((x zip y):\o)((n,m)=>{val s=Seq(if(n._1==l)'0'else l,m(0),n._2).filter(_==l).size
Seq("01","00","11","10")(s)}+m.tail)
def M(a:S,b:S)=if(b==o)a else t(x(n(a,b),n(b,a)))
def d(n:S,m:S):S=if(g(n,m))P(D(M(n,m),m),"1")else o
def D(a:S,b:S)=t(d(n(a,b),n(b,a)))
def t(s:S)={val r=(s.substring(s.size-math.min(s.size,32))).replaceAll("^0*","")
if(r=="")o else r}
}
```

As usual, I have a less golfed version too, to explain 1 or 2 points (and this thread has much space left):

```
object BinArithmetic {
  def normalize (v: String, cmp: String) = "0" * (cmp.size - v.size) + v    
  def ge(n:String, m:String)=((n zip m)find(a=>a._1!=a._2)).getOrElse(('1','0'))._1=='1'
  def greaterEqual (a:String, b:String): Boolean = ge (normalize (a, b), normalize (b, a))
  def i(s:String)=if(s=="0")"0"else trim32(j(s))
  def j(s:String):String=if(s.size==0)""else{if(s(0)=='1')'0'else'1'}+j(s.tail)
  def add (x:String, y: String): String = 
   (((x zip y) :\ "0")((b, a) => {
       List (a(0), b._1, b._2).filter (_ == '1').size match {
        case 0 => "00"
        case 1 => "01"
        case 2 => "10"
        case 3 => "11"
        }
    }+a.tail))
  def plus (a:String, b:String): String = {
    trim32 (add (normalize (a, b), normalize (b, a)))
  }    
  def mul (a:String, b: String): String =("0" /: a.zipWithIndex.filter (_._1 == '1').map (x=> b+ "0" * (a.size - x._2 - 1)))(plus)
  def sub(x:String, y: String): String = trim32(s(x,y))
  def s(x:String, y: String): String = 
   ((x zip y) :\ "0")((b, ü) => {
       List (if(b._1=='1')'0' else '1', ü(0), b._2).filter (_ == '1').size match {
        case 0 => "01"
        case 1 => "00"
        case 2 => "11"
        case 3 => "10"
        }
    }+ü.tail)      
  def minus (a:String, b:String): String = if (b=="0") a else {
    trim32 (sub (normalize (a, b), normalize (b, a)))
  }
  def d(n:String,m:String):String=if(ge(n,m))plus(div(minus(n,m),m),"1")else "0"
  def div (a:String, b:String): String = {
    trim32 (d (normalize (a, b), normalize (b, a)))
  }
  def trim32 (s: String): String = {
    val res = (s.substring (s.length - math.min (s.length, 32))).replaceAll ("^0*", "")
    if (res == "") "0" else res 
  }
}
```

Half way through golfing and obfuscating the code I changed the methods *add* and *s(ub)* a bit. Later I recognized that I didn't used the methods *i(nv)* and *j* which handled inversing numbers - my research showed that you can inverse a number as binary string, you can add "1" and so `sub (a, b)` should theoretically be the same as `add (add (a, inv(b)), "1")` but in practice, it isn't. :)

There are 4 sorts of Methods:

- preparation (normalize (a,b)) for example, which takes tow numbers, and makes them equal long
- core calculation methods (add, sub, mul, div)
- wrapping methods, which usually take (a,b) and normalize the call to the calculation methods with similar names (plus, minus)
- finishing methods, which post process the result (trim32)

The root is the add method.

```
def a(x:S, y: S) = (((x zip y) :\ "0")((n, m) => {
  val s=List (m(0), n._1, n._2).filter (_ == '1').size
  List ("00", "01", "10", "11") (s)
  }+m.tail))
```

:\ is the right-fold operator. x zip y produces the list of pairs (10), (01), (11) from "101", "011", combines it with the overrun of the last operation, starting with no such overrun 0, counts the 1s in the result and produces a micro String like "10" from it. The 0 gets the growing part of the output, while 1 is the new overrun. You learned that at elementary school, didn't you? Now you remember!

The mul - method is interesting:

```
def mul (a:String, b: String): String =
  ("0" /: a.zipWithIndex.filter (_._1 == '1').map (x=> b+ "0" * (a.size - x._2 - 1)))(plus)
```

From mul ("1010", "0110"), it takes a and zips with index ("1010"->0123 => 10, 01, 12, 03) filters those which are 1 in a: (10, 12) takes the b and adds (a.size=4 - (x._2=[0,2]) - 1) times a literal "0". 4-0-1 = 3, 4-2-1=1 => "0110"+"000", "0110"+"0". The result is put into the already defined plus operation, which is a normalized add.

div is just subtraction combined with addition:

```
def d (n:String, m:String):String=
  if (greaterEqual (n,m)) plus (div (minus (n, m), m),"1") else "0"

if (n > m) then n/m = (n-m)/m + 1 else 0
if (8 > 3)      8/3 = (8-3)/3 + 1
if (5 > 3)      8/3 = (5-3)/3 + 1 + 1 
since ! (2 > 3) 8/3 =       0 + 1 + 1
```

Sub is just similar implemented like add. Thanks to cyclic nature of ints, it doesn't really matter if the result is positive or negative.

Maybe I try the 2s-complement part later again.

Invocation

```
val ba = B
ba.plus  (  "01010",   "10101") // 11111
res412: String = 11111
ba.minus (  "11110",   "01010") // 10100
res413: String = 10100
ba.mul   (   "0010",    "1000") // 10000
res414: String = 10000
ba.div   ("1011010", "0010001") // 101
res415: String = 101
```

Answer (score 3):

### Smalltalk Squeak 4.x flavour, 570 bytes

**First Try**: define an operator in Object to evaluate any Object:

```
`x^self cull:x
```

We refine the eval message in Character to get the value:

```
`x^value
```

Then define bit ops with binary messages in Character:

```
&x^self class value:(x`1bitAnd:value)

|x^self class value:(x`1bitOr:value)

/x^self class value:((x`1bitXor:value)bitXor:$0`1)
```

/ is xor operator, because it looks like the truth table

```
01
10
```

Then add two more messages in Character for repeating in a String and concatanating

```
*n^String new:n withAll:self

,s^(String with:self),s
```

Or my favourite hack to gain 2 chars:

```
,s^'',(self`1+#[0]),s
```

Now create a new notation for accessing Array elements because `(x at:i)` costs two much. The operator @ could be used for at: and <@ would then means that it starts from the right (0-based) because our bit-Strings are big-endian.

That would be

```
Object subclass:#At instanceVariableNames:'a i'classVariableNames:''poolDictionaries:''category:''
```

In At, we would define two methods for initializing and accessing:

```
a:b i:j a:=b.i:=j

`x^(a atWrap:0-i)`x
```

Since this costs to much, we will replace this nice thing by using Association. So we define the accessor message in String (or in SequenceableCollection)

```
<@i^self->i
```

And just define ` to retrieve the At value in Association:

```
`x^(key atWrap:0-value)`x
```

Now we are ready to implement the operations in String first, strip the $0 left:

```
\~c |x|(x:=self)size>1or:[^x].c=(x at:1)or:[^x].^x allButFirst\~c
```

Then the awfull bit sum +| (just a naive xor with carry)

```
+|y|x z c m n|(m:=(x:=self)size)<=(n:=y size)or:[^y+|x].c:=$0.z:=''.0to:m-1do:[:i|z:=c/(x<@i)/(y<@i),z.c:=c|(y<@i)&(x<@i)|(c&(y<@i))].m to:n-1do:[:i|z:=c/(y<@i),z.c:=c&(y<@i)].c=$0or:[^c,z].^z
```

Then the bit multiply *| :

```
*|y|x z|x:=self.z:='0'.0to:y size-1do:[:i|$0/(y<@i)=$0or:[z:=z+|x].x:=x,$0].^z
```

Then the bit subtraction -| is using two complement. Result is truncated to receiver length, so it must not be negative:

```
-|y|n x|n:=(x:=self\~$0)size.^(x+|'1'+|($1*n,(y collect:[:c|c/$1])))last:n
```

Then a test <| for bit less than:

```
<|y|m n|m:=self size.n:=y size.^m<n or:[m=n and:[self<y]]
```

Then the bit division /| (by subtraction) - this will also raise a zero divide exception when appropriate:

```
/|z| x y q t n|y:=z\~$0.x:=self\~$0.y='0'and:[1/0].n:=0max:x size-y size.q:=''.[n>=0]whileTrue:[t:=y,($0*n).n:=n-1.q:=q,(x<|t ifTrue:[$0]ifFalse:[x:=x-|t\~$0.$1])].^q
```

And finally the operation encoding - we reuse <@ to access right to left 0-based:

```
y:y o:o|x|x:=self.^({[x/|y].[x*|y].[x-|y].[x+|y]}<@o)`1\~$0
```

The small test suite:

```
self assert: ('01010' y:'10101' o:0) = '11111'.
self assert:('11110' y:'01010' o:1) = '10100'.
self assert:('0010' y:'1000' o:2) = '10000'.
self assert:('1011010' y:'0010001' o:3) = '101'.
```

The longer test suite:

```
| n |
n := 100.
0 to: n do: [:i|0 to:n do:[:j | 
    self assert:  (i printStringBase:2)+|(j printStringBase:2)\~$0=(i+j printStringBase:2)]].
0 to: n do: [:i|0 to:n do:[:j | 
    self assert:  (i printStringBase:2)*|(j printStringBase:2)\~$0=(i*j printStringBase:2)]].
0 to: n do: [:i|0 to:i do:[:j | 
    self assert:  (i printStringBase:2)-|(j printStringBase:2)\~$0=(i-j printStringBase:2)]].
0 to: n do: [:i|1 to:n do:[:j | 
    self assert:  (i printStringBase:2)/|(j printStringBase:2)\~$0=(i//j printStringBase:2)]].
```

And the score is given by:

```
{Object>>#`. SequenceableCollection>>#<@. Association>>#`}
    , ({#`. #*. #&. #|. #/. #,} collect:[:selector | Character>>selector])
    , ({#\~. #+|. #-|. #*|. #/|. #<|. #y:o:} collect:[:selector | String>>selector])
    detectSum: [:method | method getSource size].
```

Which is 921 chars...

---

We can do much better if we use Boolean instead of Integer. They can be easily transformed in character:

Implement in True:

```
c^$1
```

And in False:

```
c^$0
```

Now transform a binary Character in Boolean, implement in Character:

```
b^self=$1
```

Now logical operations are expressed much simply in Character:

```
&x^(x b&self b)c

|x^(x b|self b)c

/x^(x b xor:self b)c
```

Plus the two operations to repeat and concatenate:

```
*n^String new:n withAll:self

,s^self*1,s
```

Now, the message size is long, let's create a shorter binary message in String:

```
\n^self size-n
```

We shorten the message for stripping leading chars in String:

```
~c|x|(x:=self)\1<1or:[c~=(x at:1)or:[^(x last:x\1)~c]]
```

Now we'd better implement binary >= rather than < for division, let's call it >~ in String:

```
>~y^self\0>(y\0)or:[self\0=(y\0)and:[self>=y]]
```

Now back to the operations, we will call them + - * / even if we have to override existing methods in String (they are presumably not used):

```
y:y o:o|x|x:=self.^({[x/y].[x*y].[x-y].[x+y]}<@o)value~$0

+y|x z c m n|(m:=(x:=self)\1)<=(n:=y\1)or:[^y+x].c:=$0.z:=''.0to:m do:[:i|z:=c/(x<@i)/(y<@i),z.c:=c|(y<@i)&(x<@i)|(c&(y<@i))].m+1to:n do:[:i|z:=c/(y<@i),z.c:=c&(y<@i)].c=$0or:[^c,z].^z

-y|n x|n:=(x:=self~$0)\0.^(x+'1'+($1*n,(y collect:[:c|c/$1])))last:n

*y|z|z:='0'.0to:y\1do:[:i|(y<@i)b and:[z:=self,($0*i)+z]].^z

/z| x y q t|y:=z~$0.x:=self~$0.y='0'and:[1/0].q:=''.(0max:x\0-(y\0))to:0by:-1do:[:n|t:=y,($0*n).q:=q,(x>~t and:[x:=x-t~$0.$1b])c].^q
```

The score is now

```
methods := {SequenceableCollection>>#<@. True>>#c. False>>#c}
    , ({#b. #*. #&. #|. #/. #,} collect:[:selector | Character>>selector])
    , ({#\. #~. #+. #-. #*. #/. #>~. #y:o:} collect:[:selector | String>>selector]).
methods detectSum: [:method | method getSource size].
```

That is 742 chars

Another snippet to browse our code alltogether:

```
methods do: [:e | e methodClass organization classify: e selector under: '*CodeGolfBinaryArithmetic'].
SystemNavigation default
    browseMessageList:
        (methods collect: [:e | MethodReference class: e methodClass selector: e selector])
    name: 'CodeGolfBinaryArithmetic'
```

We can further reduce the division to repeated subtraction (slower):

```
/z|x y|y:=z~$0.x:=self~$0.y='0'and:[1/0].x>~y or:[^'0'].^x-y/y+'1'
```

We can also omit 1/0 for ZeroDivide exception, anyway the result will be infinite on a computer with infinite memory after an infinite time:

```
/z|x y|y:=z~$0.x:=self~$0.x>~y or:[^'0'].^x-y/y+'1'
```

We can also reduce addition to a recursive form:

```
+y|x|(x:=self)\0>0or:[^y].y\0>0or:[^x].^x<@0&(y<@0)*1+(x first:x\1)+(y first:y\1),(x<@0/(y<@0))
```

And we now are at 570 chars... Not bad for Smalltalk.