# Make a zigzag pattern

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your task is to take in one integer input and print a zigzag pattern using slashes and backslashes.

- The integer input determines the length of each zig and zag, as well as the number of zigs and zags
- The pattern always starts from right to left

## Test Cases

```
4->
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
2->
 /
/
\
 \
0->
1->
/
8->
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \
       \
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \
       \
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \
       \
       /
      /
     /
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \
       \
```

Comment: Can we output an array/list of strings for each line? Are training or leading newlines or spaces allowed?

Comment: Is leading whitespace okay as long as the pattern is unaffected?

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>16</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ＦＮ«↖Ｉθ→‖Ｔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLM6AoM69Ewyq0wCc1rURHwTmxuESjUFPTmovTN78sVcMqKDM9owTEDUpNy0lNLgkpSswrBpqVqwEUrP3/3@S/btl/3eIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: [this works](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NToZqLM6AoM69Ewyq0wCc1rURHwTmxuESjUFPTmovTN78sVcMqKDM9owTEDUpNy0lNLgkpSswrBpqVqwEUrP3/3@S/btl/3eIcAA) (Was `InputNumber` broken in golfy mode too?)

Comment: @ASCII-only No, thus the separate links to the given succinct version and the approximate verbose version.

Comment: Oh >_> didn't look to see which link I was opening

Comment: @ASCII-only Well there's only one link now ;-)

Answer (score 10):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>108</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>98</s> <s>80</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

- Saved six bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen); removing parentheses and golfing `N-n-1` to `N+~n`
- Saved a byte by moving `Z`'s incrementation into the loop condition
- Saved three bytes by using `printf("%c\n",...)` instead of `putchar(...)` and `,puts("")`
- Saved eighteen (!) bytes thanks to [HatsuPointerKun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72535/hatsupointerkun); using `printf("%*s",n,"");` to print `n` spaces instead of using a loop `j;for(j=n;j--;)putchar(32);` and combining both `printf(...);` calls
- Saved four bytes by using `printf("%*c",-~n,...);` instead of `printf("%*s%c",n,"",...);`
- Saved four bytes thanks to [nwellnhof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9296/nwellnhof); moving everything inside one loop instead of two

```c
j;f(k){for(j=0;j<k*k;j++)printf("%*c\n",j/k%2?j%k+1:k-j%k,j/k%2?92:47);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/LOk0jW7M6Lb9II8vWwDrLJlsr2zpLW1uzoCgzryRNQ0lVKzkmT0knSz9b1cg@SzVb29AqWxdIQ0UsjaxMzDWta/97WecmZuZpQIzysq0zsPbS1rYxNLDWTNPw0tQpKC0p1lBSAqkEAA)

Comment: [`Z,n,j;f(N){for(Z=0;Z<N;Z++)for(n=N;n--;putchar(Z%2?92:47),puts(""))for(j=Z%2?N+~n:n;j--;)putchar(32);}`](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9KJ08nyzpNw0@zOi2/SCPK1sA6ysbPOkpbWxPEz7P1s87T1bUuKC1JzkgEyqsa2VsaWZmYa@oAhYo1lJQ0weqybEEyftp1eVZ51llADZowHcZGmta1/72scxMz8zQgllh7aWvbGBpYa6ZpeCHMAaoCAA) **102 bytes**. Removed the curly brackets by putting everything inside the loops; and changed `N-n-1` to `N+~n`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. Saved another byte by swapping both `Z%2?...:...` and replacing `Z<N;Z++` with `Z++<N;`.

Comment: You can save several bytes by using the printf magic like i did in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143483/72535). That way you will get rid of the for loop used to print spaces. For more details, see this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448093/6784509) about left padding spaces with printf

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun Thanks; that is a really short way to repeat spaces in C.

Comment: 4 bytes shorter: `i;f(N){for(i=0;i<N*N;i++)printf("%*c\n",i/N%2?i%N+1:N-i%N,i/N%2?92:47);}`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk3DT7M6Lb9II9PWwDrTxk/LzzpTW1uzoCgzryRNQ0lVKzkmT0knU99P1cg@U9VP29DKTxdIQ0UsjaxMzDWta/8rK5ibcnlZ5yZm5mlAzLP20ta2MTSw1kzT8NLUKSgtKdZQUgIpBQA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @nwellnhof Thanks. I was wondering if it would be shorter in a single loop; great that it is!

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
:"GXy@o?P47}92]*c
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30rJPaLSId8@wMS81tIoViv5/38TAA)

#### Explanation

```
:         % Implicit input, n. Push range [1 2 ... n]
"         % For each k in that range
  G       %   Push n again
  Xy      %   Identity matrix of that size
  @       %   Push k
  o?      %   If it's odd
    P     %     Flip the matrix upside down
    47    %     Push 47 (ASCII for '/')
  }       %   Else
    92    %     Push 92 (ASCII for '\')
  ]       %   End
  *       %   Multiply each entry of the matrix by that number
  c       %   Convert to char. Char 0 is shown as space
          % Implicit end. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform),  <s>117</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

```cs
a=>{for(int z=a+1,e=0;e<a*a;)System.Console.WriteLine(e++/a%2<1?"/".PadLeft(--z):@"\".PadLeft(z++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv/YpQEBJjWxVPtqmK1woFD168rOkWAjWRJgq29Ntj0YJzmeHNLoy0kTQt@sfz1ihJZAPWkjLog4CMmqh14EZ7GVWREyhN2bedjsj5bR3e44N0yuhMaZeTmggPIu9r09IRkE4AXy1QLFPMYA4pm36ORlvTYHxplcNCaaTIeQKzdbbahUkYl1AVWDsaRR3b7sPrn3ScM5YOPv1tqOmGTXEIBv8B)

Comment: You can save 14 bytes like this: [`a=>{var o="";for(int z=a+1,e=0;e<a*a;)o+=(e++/a%2<1?"/".PadLeft(--z):@"\".PadLeft(z++))+"\n";return o;}` **103 bytes**](https://tio.run/##VY5Ni8IwFEX3/RWPgJAYWz@YlWlUEGalIMxiNm7exFcJ1ESSVJhKf3stUhjmbi6cexbXxNz4QP29@amtAVNjjHDKnlkGQ0YaE6ahHt5e4IjWcfFeRwm@fmOiW/HZOFNal2YxBeuuG6hA96g3zwcG8JoxVfnABwFajXI5I71QVOIUlfBSc5JyjpNVudyyOStOeDlQlXiet2K9Y@c/0kophGRnx1Sg1AQHXnW9@ndl7130NRXfwSY6WEe84h9CjFKXdf0L) You don't need all those parenthesis; you can combine the `int`; and only add `+"\n"` once.

Comment: Hmm, you can save 2 more bytes by printing directly, instead of returning a string: [`a=>{for(int z=a+1,e=0;e<a*a;)System.Console.WriteLine(e++/a%2<1?"/".PadLeft(--z):@"\".PadLeft(z++));}` **101 bytes**](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv/YpQEBJjWxVPtqmK1woFD168rOkWAjWRJgq29Ntj0YJzmeHNLoy0kTQt@sfz1ihJZAPWkjLog4CMmqh14EZ7GVWREyhN2bedjsj5bR3e44N0yuhMaZeTmggPIu9r09IRkE4AXy1QLFPMYA4pm36ORlvTYHxplcNCaaTIeQKzdbbahUkYl1AVWDsaRR3b7sPrn3ScM5YOPv1tqOmGTXEIBv8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
╝F{±↔}P}ø
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyNTVERiU3QiVCMSV1MjE5NCU3RFAlN0QlRjg_,inputs=NA__)

could be 8 bytes `╝F{±↔}P}` if the 0 test-case wasn't required

Explanation:

```
       }   implicitly started loop repeated input times
╝            create a down-right diagonal of the input
 F           get the current looping index, 1-indexed
  {  }       that many times
   ±↔          reverse the diagonal horizontally
      P      print that
        ø  push an empty string - something to implicitly print if the loop wasn't executed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 62 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech</sup>

```python
lambda n:[[~i,i][i/n%2]%n*' '+'/\\'[i/n%2]for i in range(n*n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcixDkAwFAXQX3mLvBYhEZPEl7QdKpQn3Epjsfj1WpzxXM@9RXQ5jDYf/pxmTxiMeaUWZ6RF0bkCJRNX3FrLf4WYSEhAyWNdFEpol68kuIktuNmjQAXVa50/)

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##LchBC0AwGAbgv/K1kg1RclJ@ybbDxPjEOy0XF399HJyees77WgPa5AeTdneMkyP0Wj@SM6gS1YfV3CBrbSFIlKIxRvzhQyQmBkWHZZYooGw6I@Oi3CCvt8CQXnZKpRc).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 84 <del>90</del> bytes

```mathematica
(n=#;Grid@Array[If[Abs[n-(s=Mod[#-1,2n])-.5]==#2-.5,If[s<n,"‌​/","\\"],""]&,{n^2,n‌​}])&
```

- *Thank Jenny_mathy for -6 bytes.*

I have no idea why `\` is obviously darker than `/`.

[image]

Comment: 84 bytes `(n=#;Grid@Array[If[Abs[n-(s=Mod[#-1,2n])-.5]==#2-.5,If[s<n,"/","\\"],""]&,{n^2,n}])&`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>94</s> 89 bytes

```
["/","\\"][range($n)%2]as$s|range($n)|[(range(if$s=="/"then$n-.-1 else. end)|" "),$s]|add
```

Explanation

```
  ["/","\\"][range($n)%2] as $s                         # for $s= / \ / \ $n times 
| range($n)                                             # for .=0 to $n-1
| [(range(if $s=="/" then $n-.-1 else . end)|" "), $s]  # form list of spaces ending with $s
| add                                                   # concatenate
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mnr --argjson n 5 '["/","\\"][range($n)%2]as$s|range($n)|[(range(if$s=="/"then$n-.-1 else. end)|" "),$s]|add'
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
    /
   /
  /
 /
/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCsMgEAC/IssWImRTWnrNS4wHQdtaZE2zhlx8e61Q6G1mYF7vdlNOFHJtBs4wwrKANZvjRxiQ9elqnaDUf6hm@HG8o8xzX8ozMDJNdFEhSZhUYK8rKNAjiq3O@9Y@eS0xszQi3lOiyOteumzuoLyXLl8)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>140</s> <s>134</s> 116 bytes

```java
n->{String r="";for(int a=0,b,c;a++<n;)for(b=n;b-->0;r+=a%2>0?"/\n":"\\\n")for(c=b-n+b|-a%2;++c<b;r+=" ");return r;}
```

-24 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZDBasMwEETv/YpFULBQ5Lqhh1JF7hc0lx7rHlaKUpQ6ayPLgZL6213Z8bUYJMTOm4UZnfCCsmkdnQ7fo62x6@ANPV3vADxFF45oHeynEeA9Bk9fYLNEgLhK4pBuOl3E6C3sgUDDSLK8Lt6gGVPHJswrqIuN2ViFQuxI8Uk2mpSRsixUEBrvt2Xxyh4qYi@sqtIze6w2koT5lYkrIezOTGYGjKvgYh8IghpGdUvS9qZOSZZAl8Yf4Jz6ZLc8H5@AfCnz00V3zps@5m1CsaaMcpsVfO71L39c4dsV/rTCn/nyr8P4Bw)

```java
n->{                // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  String r="";      //  Result-String
  for(int a=0,b,c;  //  Index integers
      a++<n;)       //  Loop (1) from 0 to the input (exclusive)
    for(b=n;        //   Reset `b` to the input
        b-->0;      //   Inner loop (2) from the input to 0 (exclusive)
                    //     After every iteration: 
        r+=a%2>0?"/\n":"\\\n") 
                    //      Append either of the slashes + a new-line
      for(c=b-n+b|-a%2;++c<b;r+=" ");
                    //    Append the correct amount of spaces
                    //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                    //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;         //  Return the result-String
}                   // End of method
```

Comment: The condition of the innermost loop can be written as `c-->f*(b-n-~b)` (-6 bytes).

Comment: 116 bytes: `n->{String r="";for(int a=0,b,c;a++<n;)for(b=n;b-->0;r+=a%2>0?"/\n":"\\\n")for(c=b-n+b|-a%2;++c<b;r+=" ");return r;}`

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ES8, <strike>83</strike> <strike>79</strike> <strike>78</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>75</strike> <strike>74</strike> 71 bytes

*reduced 1 byte with ES8 thanks to Shaggy

```
A=(m,i=0)=>i<m*m?`/\\`[x=i/m&1].padStart(x?i%m+1:m-i%m)+`
`+A(m,++i):""
```

[Test here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f/f0VYjVyfT1kDT1i7TJlcr115JQUmvKLUgNbFEI1M/V83QPlM11ypXF0jqGmpqK@nHxChFZ2prg6RitZVi8pS0HUEmaFopKf1Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dw1DDU1LTmQhUywhQyxhQyAQr9BwA)

Comment: whoever downvoted my solution, could you explain why? Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I assume that it is because functions need to be repeatable to be valid. Yours could be fixed pretty easily by making `i` a default parameter. The byte count seem off as well.

Comment: Adding a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f/f0VYjVyfT1kDT1i7TJlcr115JQUmvKLUgNbFEI1M/V83QPlM11ypXF0jqGmpqK@nHxChFZ2prg6RitZVi8pS0HUEmaFopKf1Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dw1DDU1LTmQhUywhQyxhQyAQr9BwA) is always appreciated as well, so that people can easily test your solution.

Comment: @Emigna fixed it (char wise and Link wise) :)

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f/f0VYjVyfT1kDT1i7TJlcr115JSa8gMcU1L0UjUz9XzdA@UzXXKlcXSOoaamor6cfEKEVnamuDpGK1E7gStB1B@jWtlJT@J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrOGoYampac6EKGWEKGWMKmQCF/gMA) with some ES8. Also, for JS you can just use a Stack Snippet rather than TIO.

Comment: @Shaggy im new to StackExchange, how can i insert Stack Snippet?

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
Lm+*;dbQjs<*,_y\/y\\
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lm%2B%2a%3BdbQjs%3C%2a%2C_y%5C%2Fy%5C%5C&input=3&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 81 bytes

```powershell
param($a)if($a){1..$a|%{((1..$a|%{" "*--$_+'\'}),($a..1|%{" "*--$_+'/'}))[$_%2]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRMzMNRFYb6umpJNaoVmtowFhKCkpauroq8drqMeq1mjpAVXp6hiji@kBxzWiVeFWj2Nra////GwMA)

Ugh, this is ugly. So much repeated code, plus 7 bytes required to account for `0` special case. *Golfing suggestions welcome.*

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 17 bytes

```
js<*_+RV"\/"_B*L;
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=js%3C%2A_%2BRV%22%5C%2F%22_B%2AL%3B&input=3&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
js<*_+RV"\/"_B*L;QQQ   implicit Qs at the end
              *L;Q     list with ["", " ", "  ", ..., " "*(input-1)]
            _B         bifurcate with reverse: [["" to "   "], ["   " to ""]]
     +RV"\/"           append to each one either "\" or "/": 
                       [["\", to "   \"], ["   /" to "/"]]
    _                  reverse
   *              Q    repeat input times
  <                Q   but only take the first input many
 s                     flatten the list of lists
j                      print on each line
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
F<„/\Nèú.sNƒR}»,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzeZRwzz9GL/DKw7v0iv2OzYpqPbQbp3//00A)

**Explanation**

```
F                  # for N in [0 ... input-1] do
  „/\              # push the string "/\"
     Nè            # cyclically index into this string with N
 <     ú           # prepend input-1 spaces to this string
        .s         # get suffixes
          NƒR}     # reverse the list of suffixes input+1 times
              »,   # join on newline and print
```

**Current best attempt using canvas:**

```
F„/\Nè©53NèΛ2®ð«4Λ
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3: <s>90 Bytes</s> 82 Bytes

```
lambda n:"\n".join(" "*(abs(i%(n*2)-n+i//n%2)-1)+"/\\"[i//n%2]for i in range(n*n))
```

Thanks to @Jonathan Frech for pointing out that print wasn't needed and that the first zig was the wrong way

Comment: `] for` -> `]for`.

Comment: You do not need the `print(...)`, a function returning a string would be valid. Also, I think your initial zig is oriented the wrong way (\ rather than /).

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thanks! I changed it

Comment: `(abs(...)-1)` -> `~-abs(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```cpp
void m(int n){for(int i=0,j;i<n;++i)for(j=0;j<n;++j)printf("%*c\n",i%2?j+1:n-j,i%2?92:47);}
```

Thanks to the power of the magic `printf`

Comment: You can put the `int i=0,j` in the for-loop `for(int i=0,j;i<n;++i)` to save a byte.

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYxRC4IwFEb/SiyErU0yCSSvq/f9hl5iZtzRrkPnU@RfN2cvH4ePw7Eh5C9rlz2SfU/ts7FjbLG/Lkhx53laEp@uHzZEXSgHTqOUDYFIN9DRgZROhGE1Os6yg70TU5iVt9zlM9Vu43NVX0oB3y1swD@Q@D9s9FyAWYunAoTnRqgwxZEzluwf "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>131</s> <s>106</s> <s>98</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 91 bytes

```java
i->{for(int j=0;j<i*i;System.out.printf("%"+(j/i%2<1?i-j%i:j%i+1)+"c\n",47+45*(j++/i%2)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BSsQwFEX3/YpQKCSNjY5UBNMZEVeuZ6kuYiYtL7ZJSV4GZOi311Rm4YW3OfdxOVadVeNn4@zpe4Vp9gGJzUwgTEbUsvjPEsIo@uQ0gndbWehRxUheyKUgOREVgibk1buYJhO6N4dmMOFAEtmv0BwuvQ8UXJ7b30nbQQ3y@BPRTMInFHPIVU/LquTU3kJ13@2eobEVPOXjO8ZL/eHKm/aRtw81tZxvP4wxuaxZZROY09eYBa4eZw8nMilw9Ih5enj/JCoMkV1ttyShtDYz0pbJP7gUy/oL)

Comment: You can remove quite a few parentheses: `i->{for(int j=0;j<i*i;System.out.printf("%"+(j/i%2<1?i-j%i+1:j%i+2)+"s",j++/i%2<1?"/\n":"\\\n"));}` (98 bytes).

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>39</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```apl
{↑((,⍵ ⍵⍴(⌽,⊢)⍳⍵)/¨' '),¨⍵/⍵⍴'/\'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLjSgGT1o7aJGho6j3q3KgDxo94tGo969uo86lqk@ah3M1BEU//QCnUFdU2dQyuAPH2IGnX9GPVaLqBBQAPSFEz//wcA)

1 byte saved thanks to [Zacharý](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55550/zachar%c3%bd)

Comment: Dang it, beat me by one byte. You can make `⎕IO` be `0`, and then remove `¯1+`.

Comment: @Zacharý I was just about to do that :p

Comment: Oh, one more thing: `(⌽,⊢)⍳⍵` instead of `(⌽⍳⍵),⍳⍵`

Comment: @Zacharý Yeah, I'm yet to understand the tacks, tacitness and stuff that comes with that :/

Comment: Don't worry, I don't fully understand how trains/forks/whatever-they're-called work either.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 70 + 1 (`-n`) = 71 bytes

```perl
$n=$_**2;$_=$"x--$_.'/';say&&s% /%/ %||s%\\ % \\%||y%\\/%/\\%while$n--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAr0jsGgSrFnUKn9APBOkgJIRFBhX09jZvw@zhWAdmSBZ803QjeAvVTQRe1boe8/xImVFo1ALfN6NzAoVzxU9x6eJriWuARMTcf9t@xi1lpmlQpjVM6Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>84</s></sub> 83 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[A1]:For j=1To[A1]:?IIf(i mod 2,Space([A1]-j)&"/",Space(j-1)&"\"):Next j,i
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 102 bytes

```
(0..q-1).map{r->if(r%2<1)q-1 downTo 0 else{0..q-1}.map{(1..it).map{print(' ')};println('/'+45*(r%2))}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BDoIwEETvfMWGxLCraQXFCyKJR8/6A00E0ggFSo0R0m9HLDqnyezbmUdjKqmm4qlgwC65KENwgglDzjsWEa9FO2qWyQL1apdGNIdwb17q1kAIedXn40JaR2LEuTTLV6ulMhhAQPbofKUw2Aab@LD@dhFZ62ZrIRUKXfYJnLUW7/RqZrrMCEYPZg0YkzP/Ep8x5tPvtifPTh8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ḶṚ⁶ẋm0ż⁾/\x$ṁ²Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4bi24bma4oG24bqLbTDFvOKBvi9ceCThuYHCsln///84)

Full program.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```hs
f n=take(n*n)$cycle$[(' '<$[x..n-1])++"/"|x<-[1..n]]++[(' '<$[2..x])++"\\"|x<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz7YkMTtVI08rT1MluTI5J1UlWkNdQd1GJbpCTy9P1zBWU1tbSV@ppsJGN9oQKBIbq60NU2Gkp1cBlo@JQVbwPzcxM0/BViElX4FLAQhyEwt8FQpKS4JLinzyFFQU0hRM/wMA)

*Saved one byte thanks to Laikoni*

Repeat a zig ++ a zag, and take the first `n*n` lines.

Comment: `cycle$ ...` instead of `cycle( ... )` saves a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>39 35 33 32</s> 25 bytes

```
' /\'{~[,/@$(|.,:+:)@=@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P9FWT0FdQT9GvbouWkffQUWjRk/HSttK08HWIVPvf2pyRr5CooIJF5RhCGMY/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

`⎕IO` must be `0`.

```
{⍪/((⌽⍵ ⍵⍴S↑'/')(⍵ ⍵⍴'\'↑⍨S←⍵+1))[2|⍳⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVE//R20TDLiALCBd/ah3lb6GxqOevY96tyoA8aPeLcGP2iaq66traiCE1GPUgYKPelcA5SYAhbQNNTWjjWoe9W4GcmJrTf//BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 105 bytes

```d
import std.stdio;void m(T)(T n){for(T i,j;i<n;++i)for(j=0;j<n;++j)printf("%*c\n",i%2?j+1:n-j,i%2?92:47);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/n/PzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrcvyM1MUcjVCNDVCFPI0q9Pyi4CMTJ0s60ybPGtt7UxNkEiWrYF1FpifpVlQlJlXkqahpKqVHJOnpJOpamSfpW1olaebBWZbGlmZmGta1/6HGJyYmaehWc3FmathomnNVfsfAA)

Lifted from HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer.